# How does Rails handle comparison between TimeWithZone and Date objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This could introduce subtle "bugs" (perceived inconsistencies), like the following:

```
>> Time.zone.parse('Tue, 01 Aug 2017 00:00:00 CEST +02:00') < Date.new(2017,8,1)
=> true
```

It seems as if Rails converts the Date to a DateTime or TimeWithZone object with '00:00:00 UTC', hence the result. Like this:

```
>> Date.new(2017,8,1).to_datetime
=> Tue, 01 Aug 2017 00:00:00 +0000
```

That would explain it. But I would like to know how Rails actually does this, and what type of object it converts it to in the process, to be sure. I didn't find it in the API docs, or the source, but maybe someone can give a step by step explanation.

The source I looked through was: [compare_with_coercion](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5473e390d362755125d2f47b64ef0a135f2fe111/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb#L134)

PS: To me it would seem saner that in this type of comparison that Rails would actually convert the TimeWithZone object to a Date object instead, thus resulting in only the date portions to be compared, so that:

```
>> Time.zone.parse('Tue, 01 Aug 2017 00:00:00 CEST +02:00') == Date.new(2017,8,1)
=> true
```

Ref:

[DateTime API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/DateTime.html)

[Date API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html)

Comment: Since `Time` is the receiver you should actually be looking at [`Time#compare_with_coercion`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5473e390d362755125d2f47b64ef0a135f2fe111/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb#L262). Coercion generally modifies the argument to be cohesive with the receiver not the other way around which makes sense

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks, that's very informative!